# Librería Javascript jsPDF lanza error y no guarda documento

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

Tengo un documento HTML el cual tengo metido la librería jquery y la de jspdf oficial, la última versión.

Tengo esta simple función que se ejecuta al cargar el documento:

```
jQuery.cacheLib = function(url, options) {
            options = $.extend(options || {}, {
                dataType: "script",
                cache: true,
                url: url
            });
            return jQuery.ajax(options);
        };


        $.cacheLib(jspdf).done(function(script, textStatus) {
            var doc = new jsPDF();

            doc.text(20, 20, 'Hola mundo');
            doc.text(20, 30, 'Vamos a generar un pdf desde el lado del cliente');

            // Add new page
            doc.addPage();
            doc.text(20, 20, 'Prueba1');

            // Save the PDF
            doc.save('documento.pdf');
        });
```

Independientemente del código que tenga, me aparece esto en la consola del navegador y no ejecuta nada.

```
libs.min.js:10961 dropping module because define wasn't a string.
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.
at o (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:87:3993)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:87:5426)
```

He probado con varias librerías jQuery y jsPDF con idéntico resultado.

Comment: Los errores también se pueden incluir como texto pero bueh.

Comment: No creo que eso sea lo crítico, o si?

Comment: Crítico o no, hace más dispendioso e incluso difícil ayudarte. Si alguien tiene una discapacidad, no puede leer igual tu pregunta; si alguien te lee desde un móvil, es mucho más difícil leer tu pregunta. No eres novato, seguro ya hiciste el recorrido y sabes de qué van las recomendaciones.

Comment: No contaba con que no se pudiera leer desde todas las plataformas y dispositivos. Ahora lo corrijo.

Comment: Estás minificando todo en un único JS?

Comment: He editado la funcionalidad de carga asíncrona de la librería y qué utilizo para ella.

Comment: ¿Es la variable `jspdf` una URL?

Comment: la he llamado así aquí pero en la aplicación se llama otra cosa y no coincide en nombre. Si, esa variable tiene la ruta del fichero jspdf.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el problema esté en el orden que incluyes tus scripts para ser cargados.

De acuerdo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39628402/236345), es posible que este sea el problema. Cambia el orden en el que cargas los recursos JS

Comment: en ese orden de recursos solo prueba $(document).ready(function(){ 
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(22);

 doc.text(20, 30, 'Hola mundo');
 doc.text(20, 40, 'pdf del lado del cliente');
 doc.addPage();

 
 // 
 doc.save('Test.pdf');
});

Comment: Pues estoy cargando los scripts después de que se cargue la página y su librería, la de jsPDF la cargo de forma asíncrona con una función para hacer esto. ¿Podría ser la causa?

Answer (score 0):

Qué curioso, si a través de esta función llamo a la librería de jsPDF a un archivo en mi local, no funciona. Sin embargo si lo llamo online, si. En cambio con otras librerías, no me sucede...

Comment: Esto era, no podía utilizar ese código para llamar a la librería.